# Postgres continuously showing hight CPU usage

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a postgres9.5 installed on a Linux machine and for the last few days, it is continuously showing a huge CPU usage(80%-90%). I try to check pg_stat_activity table to find long-running queries or sessions but there is not anything to blame for and also I check that I have indexed on all my table but still CPU usage is a spike up from the Postgres process. Is there any way to figure out the reason?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about Java eating all your memory? (how much memory do you have?)

Comment: I have a total 6GB RAM. I am not considering that the java process is taking a memory right now but more worried about the CPU consumption from the Postgres side which making a slower down the java application.

Comment: If you press 'c' in `top`, it should show the full process titles, which will give some clue about what the processes are doing.  PostgreSQL updates the titles to be useful like that. You should probably make this the default setting for `top`, as it is so useful.

Comment: " I try to check pg_stat_activity table to find long-running queries or sessions but there is not anything to blame for"  Maybe you just don't know how to interpret it.  Please show us the output in case we can help.

Comment: @jjanes I update a question with partial output.

Comment: There are two top processes in `top`, and two "active" sessions in `pg_stat_activity`.  With the selection of columns you have shown us, we can't say what they are doing, but that does not seem to be a coincidence.